# How to build the project directly from svn without performing the checkout operation using Maven

Tags: svn, maven-2

I want to build the project directly from SVN without performing any checkout operations using Maven. The idea for doing this is anybody can be able to create a war/jar file irrespective of whether he/she has the code. Please suggest if you have some other approach for doing same.

Comment: Dou you mean to do the checkout via Maven ? Or what do you mean? Usually you let do the checkout a CI solution like Jenkins/Hudson and Maven builds the source into the packagages (jar, war, ear...).

Comment: Actually I don't want to checkout, but if you can share the pom.xml to check out and build the project using maven it will be helpful. Thanks for the response @khmarbaise.

Comment: You seemed to be mistaken things. To build a project you need to checkout the project and afterwards you can build the project using Maven. Can you elaborate a little bit more what you like to achieve?

Comment: Sorry if I am asking the silly questions, I am a newbie to Maven. What I want is, a way to directly create a jar/war file from the source present at the SVN repository. Is there any way to do this using Maven or please suggest if there are any other approaches for achieving this.

Comment: You have to checkout the source code onto a hard drive. You can't build inside svn....;-(

Comment: thanks for the quick responses @khmarbaise. Can you share a good tutorial for how check out the project using maven.

Comment: You don't checkout via maven. You have to checkout via SVN!!